# Integrating bash/python scripts with Selenium

Tags: python, linux, bash, selenium, cucumber-junit

I am testing a website that in production environments uses bash and python scripts to simulate users. I am familiar with Selenium (Java flavour) to test the front end but without these scripts running in the background there isn't much to test.

Is there a plug in for Selenium to run linux command/bash scripts or a separate tool all together to automate the entire process? This is a basic process that I need to automate:

Log in to Front End → check current user activity (should be 0) → run python/bash scripts → check new levels of activity are picked up by the system in the front end → run various tests on the data in the front end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you implement *Seleniums* python binding as a python script together with *Fabric*, then you should have no problems checking browser with *Selenium* and executing scripts on the external server with *Fabric*. Actually i am currently doing a similar project with *Selenium*, *Fabric* and *PhantomJS* (you could also look at that).

So have a deeper look in:

- [Fabric](http://www.fabfile.org) helps you with administrative tasks and streamlines use of ssh
- [Selenium Python Bindings](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org) allows you to access all browser document components
- [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org) for additional features - i.e. browser screenshots, page automation, performance analysis

Comment: hey thanks a lot! This looks like it might save me